# unable to migrate CI-CD across organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

I am using the version of MigrationTools-11.12.15 and trying to migrate CI-CD across org but unable to do the same.
Error[CI-CD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJbyj.png) is coming like

and my configuration file as as follows.
[Configuration.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkA1V.png)

Please advice or any suggestion on this.